# Can buttons be used in Bootstrap dropdowns instead of anchors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

A typically dropdown in Bootstrap is marked up as

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

where the items of the dropdown are anchor tags.

There are times though when the dropdown item needs to act as a `button` in that it does **not** navigate away but executes some functionality on the page.

Is there any default support for doing the following without breaking how it renders? Should I be using different classes? Or should I just duplicate the styles applied to the `.dropdown-menu > li > a` and apply it to a  `.dropdown-menu > li > button` style?

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-default">Another action</button></li>
  </ul>
```

While I know I can modify the anchor tag to execute `preventDefault()` it seems like the wrong tag and also causes the browser to show the Url as if it was navigating. Buttons do not behave like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while I did not find a built-in way of getting the button to style properly within the dropdown, explicitly setting the style to match did. Adding the following to my css file worked.

```
.dropdown-menu {

    > li > button {
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #333;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

}

.dropdown-menu > li > button {
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #262626;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
}
```